# How to use the official selenium docker images?

Tags: selenium, docker, .net-core

I am trying to set up a .NET Core Console Application that uses Selenium Webdriver with Firefox in Docker, but I am having difficulty understanding how to actually use the [official Selenium docker images](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium).

For now the console app is just an app that tries to go to Google.com and report back successfully.

I am consistently getting the following error message when trying to create a new FirefoxDriver:

> **Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line (SessionNotCreated)**

Here is the Dockerfile (generated by VSCode Docker extension + one line added by me, commented out now):

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MyAppName.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "./MyAppName.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "MyAppName.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyAppName.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .

# FROM selenium/standalone-firefox-debug ## where does this go?

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyAppName.dll"]
```

I've tried to insert the selenium standalone image at various points, attempted to start with '/bin/bash/' entrypoint to try and find if firefox is actually in the image (which it didn't seem to be, not on the regular locations). It still throws the exception.

Really all I want is to have firefox installed in my container so that I can run my .NET Core console app, but according to some google searches the simplest way to do this should be through the selenium images.

How do I properly use the selenium docker image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question just in case someone else new to Docker has the same problem and ends up here.

I figured it out.

The better way to do this is with [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) to run 3 different services: my C# script, a selenium hub service and a selenium firefox node. (you might be able to do it with *just* a script and a selenium firefox standalone image, but I'm just posting the first thing that worked for me. Will try other stuff later)

I removed the `FROM selenium/standalone-firefox-debug` statement from my .NET Core Console App Dockerfile and then put the following `docker-compose.yml` file in the same folder as my Dockerfile (most of it taken from [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45898405/8521829)):

```
version: '2'
services:
  seltest:
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - ./temp:/usr/src/app/target
    environment:
        - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=seleniumhub
        - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444
    depends_on:
        - seleniumhub
  seleniumhub:
    image: selenium/hub
    ports:
      - 4444:4444
  firefoxnode:
    image: selenium/node-firefox-debug
    ports:
      - 5900
    environment:
        - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=seleniumhub
        - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444
```

In my C# script I now had to make some changes. I had to connect my remote webdriver to the correct URI:

```
IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://seleniumhub:4444/wd/hub"), firefoxOptions);
```

(**seleniumhub**:4444 because the name of the service I create in the docker-compose.yml is *seleniumhub* and 4444 is the port opened for this service)

And because `depends_on` in docker-compose only waits for [the services to start and not until they're 'ready'](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on), I resorted to a hacky way of ensuring the selenium hub and firefox service are ready before I try to use them and just did a:

```
Thread.Sleep(10000);
```

before invoking the remote webdriver. If I **don't** do this then I get the following error trying to invoke the webdriver:

> Unhandled Exception: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: A exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://seleniumhub:4444/wd/hub/session. The status of the exception was UnknownError, and the message was: Connection refused Connection refused ---> System.Net.WebException: Connection refused Connection refused ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Connection refused ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection refused

Then I just run `docker compose up` from the command line to start the service and I can verify that my C# script made it to https://www.google.com successfully.

Seems like the whole it could be optimized in many ways, but for me the proof of concept is done!